# firebase .then() is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm attempting to get all documents in a collection.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, public router: Router) { }
    getAll() {
     this.db.collection('Completed-Forms').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
         console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      });
    });
  }
}
```

My error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.db.collection(...).get(...).then is not a function
>
> TypeError: this.db.collection(...).get(...).then is not a function

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from the bit of code you're showing here.

Comment: i've updated the post to actually supply the error as well, is it still the same case?

Comment: Can you print `this.db.collection('cities').get`?

Comment: I don't know,  What is `this.db`?  Please edit the question to distill the code down to the MCVE that removes all uncertainty about how this code executes.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: right, i've pasted the entire code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using AngularFire2, which exposes the documents as an observable.

If you want to use the regular JavaScript SDK, do

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Completed-Forms').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
```

Or (untested, but should work according to the TypeScript declarations):

```
this.db.firestore.collection('Completed-Forms').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
```

Comment: thanks, i used the second line you posted, and it works perfectly!

Comment: unfortunately votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed score.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's to prevent folks from setting up their own circle vote system to get bootstrapped. :)   You'll still be able to accept after a while though.